# Kafka How to get last committed Offset

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

The above code works great in kafka versions <2.3. But does not work afterwords.

Signature of committed changed to Map<TopicPartition,OffsetAndMetadata> committed(Set partitions)

Need result in below format. ( partitions order does not matter)
"{"topicA":{"1":4,"0":105}}"

```
  def getLatestOffset(topic: String, consumer: KafkaConsumer[String, String]): String = {


    val partitions = new util.ArrayList[TopicPartition]


    for (partitionInfo <- consumer.partitionsFor(topic)) {
      partitions.add(new TopicPartition(partitionInfo.topic, partitionInfo.partition))
    }
    consumer.assign(partitions)

    //consumer.seekToEnd(partitions)


    var map = Map[String, Long]()
    for (partition <- partitions) {

      //consumer.seekToEnd(Collections.singletonList(partition))

      // val latestOffset = consumer.position(partition)
      val latestOffset = consumer.committed(partition).offset()

      map += (partition.partition().toString -> latestOffset)

    }

    var jsonMap = Map[String, Any]()
    jsonMap += (topic -> map)


    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
    val response: String = write(jsonMap)

    response
  }
```

Comment: what is exactly the problem?

Comment: val latestOffset = consumer.committed(partition).offset() does not work . it expects partition to be set .

Comment: not sure why it was flagged down.the signature of Committed changed. It now takes set of consumer partitions, instead of partition name.I need help with that